# How can I calculate a mid-interval percentile rank in R without using a loop?

Tags: r, dplyr, percentile

I have a set of data with different groups – for this example let's just say two groups – and I want to calculate a mid-interval percentile rank, but I want to use `dplyr` (so no loop).

Here are the data and what I have so far:

```
library(dplyr);
group<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
score<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,9,10,7,8,4,5,10,11,12,13,10)
my_orig_df<-data.frame(group,score)
mydf<-my_orig_df %.%
  group_by(group) %.%
  mutate (   Cum= round( cume_dist(score),2) , myPTILE=percent_rank(score)) 
mydf
```

To be clear, I expect the first value for group `A` to be .05, not .09 nor 0.
While the results are close, they are not exactly what I am expecting.

I can obtain the desired results with a nested loop (but that is not what I want):

```
 Ugroup<-unique (group)
for (i in 1:length(Ugroup)) {
  temp<-subset(mydf,group==Ugroup[i]) 
  for(j in 1:length(temp$score)) {
    ptile<-c(ptile,    ((sum(temp$score==temp$score[j])/2)+sum(temp$score<temp$score[j]))   /length(temp$score))
  } }
```

When I run the code with a loop (above) with a large data set with multiple groups, time becomes an issue.

I have tried the following: `row_number(score); ntile(score, 99); min_rank(score); dense_rank(score); percent_rank(score); cume_dist(score)` but none result in what I am looking for. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry - I am showing my newbee status, but when I try to handle NA values, the formula above breaks! I seem to be getting a character string ratehr than a vector.  if I change the data a little: group<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","B")
score<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,9,10,7,8,4,5,10,11,12,".",10) ; score turns into a factor. I can fix this score<-as.numeric(as.character(score)); but the function doesn't work now. I can remove the NA; orig<-data.frame(group, score)
delt<-data.frame(orig[!is.na(orig$score),]); Any ideas where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to produce the same thing as your loop. Doesn't use `dplyr` though...

```
f <- function(z) sapply(z,function(x) (sum(z==x)/2+sum(z<x))/length(z))
ptile <- as.vector(t(aggregate(score~group,my_orig_df,f)[,-1]))
ptile
#  [1] 0.04545455 0.13636364 0.22727273 0.31818182 0.40909091 0.50000000 0.59090909
#  [8] 0.68181818 0.77272727 0.90909091 0.90909091 0.40909091 0.59090909 0.22727273
# [15] 0.31818182 0.04545455 0.13636364 0.59090909 0.77272727 0.86363636 0.95454545
# [22] 0.59090909
```

And here's a data.table solution that's likely to be faster.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(my_orig_df)
ptile.dt <- DT[,sapply(score,function(x)(sum(score==x)/2+sum(score<x))/.N),by=group]$V1

identical(ptile,ptile.dt)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. Two beautiful solutions! Both will provide me with plenty to work on to figure out (I am a bit of a newbee). I was hoping to run this within a call to dplyr, as it is one of many things I am attempting. While dplyr does have a do() command, I don't see how to use the current function using do(). Any other suggestions?